# Vagrant Base Box with multiple disks

Tags: vagrant

I want to create a vagrant base box that contains two disks. 
I can't see any support for it?

I know I can reference an existing virtual disk in the vagrant file, but i want to be able to distribute a pre-configured disk. If i can't add it to the box any other suggestions for getting a second pre-configured image attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the base box, you should be able to add more than 1 virtual disks in VirtualBox or whatever provider, I would take it for granted that `vagrant package` should take care of that.

If NOT, the easiest way to add a 2nd virtual disk is to use the VirtualBox GUI. After `init` and `up`, each vagrant box should have a record in VirtualBox configs. When it's off, you can use the GUI to add virtual disks and change settings. Once done, use `vagrant up` to bring it up and properly deal with it within the VM, e.g. create partition to use the whole disk, PV for LVM or btrfs up to you.

NOTE: If you are happy with command line: `VBoxManage createhd` and `VBoxManage createhd` can be used to do the same thing.

Refer to the [VirtualBox User Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/)

Comment: vagrant package works fine, that was a dumb moment... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create additional disks using options to the VirtualBox provider's customize method.

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html (VBoxManage Customizations)
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-createvdi

As seen here:
https://gist.github.com/leifg/4713995

```
file_to_disk = './tmp/large_disk.vdi'

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'base'

  config.vm.customize ['createhd', '--filename', file_to_disk, '--size', 500 * 1024]
  config.vm.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', file_to_disk]
end
```

Comment: Some caveats: 1. size is in MiB; 2. some boxes use more than one port themselves, so its safer to use like `'--port', 10`; 3. sometimes `SATA Controller` is not available and you have to use for example `SCSI`;  4. you can use `VBoxManage list vms` and then `VBoxManage showvminfo SOME_VM_NAME | grep 'Storage Controller Name'` to see what controllers are available.